# Select different bindings in DataContext based on another binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a fairly dynamic ObservableCollection of view models that is used by two different ListBox elements in XAML. Each view model contains properties for two different model objects of type `Card` called `Primary` and `Secondary`, as well as other properties. In one ListBox I'd like to display properties from `Primary` and in the other I'd like to display properties from `Secondary`. I'd like to use the same XAML UserControl file when displaying the ListBoxItems for both.

My first thought was to create an entry in UserControl.Resources that gives a name to the "right" card based on a RelativeSource reference from the parent view model which indicates `Primary` or `Secondary`, but I've not created an entry like that before. Is this the right approach? If so, what would the entry look like?

I've made up some XAML to help illustrate (may have typos). First, the Primary ListBox control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Cards.ListPrimary" d:DataContext="{Binding Main.Cards.Primary, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:CardViewModel}">
                <views:Card />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="CardListBox"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCard}"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Cards}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the secondary:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Cards.ListSecondary" d:DataContext="{Binding Main.Cards.Secondary, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    ... (same) ...
</UserControl>
```

And the card view (where I need to replace "Primary.Direction" with something that lets me select Primary/Secondary):

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Cards.Card">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        ... perhaps something here ...
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Primary.Direction}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to use the same user control for two different properties of the same class, in different places? Like, is the UserControl how you display an item in the listboxes' ItemTemplates? Just a little XAML would go a long way toward clarifying what you mean. XAML is the least ambiguous way I know to describe XAML.

Comment: How about adding a third property into the view model called CurrentCard of type Card, and setting it appropriately to point to Primary, or Secondary? Bind to that in the XAML. Doing this all in XAML could be done with a converter, perhaps. Seems like more work than what is needed to do this.

Comment: @R.Richards When using the same ObservableCollection in both ListBoxes, the ListBoxItems share the same objects. If I change CurrentCard it will unfortunately affect both ListBoxes.

Comment: You know, I read ObservableCollection, but I guess I chose to ignore that part. Sorry!! :)

Comment: @EdPlunkett The UserControl is how I display an item in ItemTemplate, and I would like to use the same UserControl to display the same view model in two different ListBoxes, where one property of the view model switches between two Card objects.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I made some XAML quickly - let me know if that helps (or if I've made a mistake). Thanks!

Comment: @R.Richards No problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two instances of the same UserControl that differ in one respect, you figure out how to parameterize that. There are a couple of ways, but the simplest I thought of that fits your case was to just bind the differing value to a property of the View. This moves the specification of the different value to the owner.

We'll do that by defining a dependency property on the UserControl. It's a string, though it could be an object, and in the future you might want to make it one. Since we're using the view in a DataTemplate, we can bind a property of the DataContext to it there.

```
public partial class Card : UserControl
{
    public Card()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public String Direction
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(DirectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DirectionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DirectionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Direction",
        typeof(String), typeof(Card), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

...and we'll use that in the UserControl like this:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
        <TextBlock 
            Text="{Binding Direction, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
            />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The `RelativeSource` stuff tells the `Binding` to look for that `Direction` property on the UserControl object itself, rather than on the `DataContext` as it would otherwise do by default.

If `Card.Direction` were object instead of string, you'd make that TextBox a ContentControl and bind to its Content property. Then you could put *anything* in there -- XAML, a whole other viewmodel, literally anything that XAML can figure out how to display.

And here's how it looks in the wild:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:CardViewModel}">
    <views:Card Direction="{Binding Primary.Direction}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

And here's my whole mainwindow content from my test code. I didn't bother creating user controls for the listboxes; the above template is an exact match for the way you're doing it.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PrimaryItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vms:CardViewModel}">
        <views:Card Direction="{Binding Primary.Direction}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SecondaryItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vms:CardViewModel}">
        <views:Card Direction="{Binding Secondary.Direction}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ListBox 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCard}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Cards}" 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PrimaryItemTemplate}"
            />
        <ListBox 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCard}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Cards}" 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SecondaryItemTemplate}"
            />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]

I originally thought of a more elaborate scheme where you give the view a DataTemplate instead, and it worked, but this is simpler. On the other hand, that was more powerful. I actually used that in the first version of the answer, before I came to my senses; it's in the edit history.

Thanks for a fun little projectlet.

Comment: This was very enlightening! I have never thought to add a dependency property to my view, probably because I've been avoiding code behind. This is very clean though, and much nicer than my workaround - thanks!